# How can I cast a '[Int]' too an 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?'?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a variable called time_diff in an app I'm making. I need to pass it into an obj-c function that takes UnsafeMutablePointer?.

Swift:

`var time_diff = [Int](repeating: 0, count: MAX_NODE)`

Obj-C Function:

```
- (instancetype) initWithRawDataX:(float *)x Y:(float*)y pressure:(float *)p time_diff:(int *)time penColor:(UInt32)penColor penThickness:(NSUInteger)thickness startTime:(UInt64)start_at size:(int)size normalizer:(float)inputScale
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Manual Memory Management in Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management.

In this case, if the function is imported into Swift as having `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>` for the type of `time_diff`, you should declare the array in swift as `[Int32]` instead of `[Int]`.  Then pass it as `&time_diff` (an `inout` argument).